# I/O from Socket in Java not reading

Tags: java, sockets

I have a set of two Java application that communicate wuth each other through Sockets. Most of the communication is automated (one sends some stuff, other receives it and computes it, sends something else). Most processes start with keyboard input from Member, which then starts exchange with server.

Server:

```
public class Server implements Runnable {

private static int port = 1234;
private Socket connection;
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private int id;
private static Primer p;
private static Map<String, Object> users;
private static BigInteger two;

public static void main(String[] args){
    two = new BigInteger("2");
    int count = 0;
    users = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    p = new Primer();
    p.keygen();
    try {
        ServerSocket ss1 = new ServerSocket(port);
        System.out.println("Serwer włączony");
        while(true){
            Socket connection = ss1.accept();
            Runnable runn = new Server(connection, ++count);
            Thread t = new Thread(runn);
            t.start();
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}

Server(Socket s, int i) {
  this.connection = s;
  this.id = i;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
@Override
public void run() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {
        InputStream inStream;
        DataInputStream inDataStream;
        OutputStream outStream;
        DataOutputStream outDataStream;
        String message="";
        String received="";
        System.out.println("Chat Server Started");
        do{
            inStream = connection.getInputStream();
            inDataStream = new DataInputStream ( inStream );
            received = inDataStream.readUTF();      
            System.out.println("Client sent: " + received);
            outStream = connection.getOutputStream();
            outDataStream = new DataOutputStream (outStream);
            analyzeREC(received, outDataStream);
            outDataStream.flush();
            //DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            //message = dis.readLine();
            //System.out.println("Enter your message here: ");
            //outDataStream.writeUTF(message);  
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }finally {
        try {
            connection.close();
        }
        catch (IOException e){}
    }
}

public void analyzeREC(String msg, DataOutputStream dos){
    String[] m = msg.split(" ");
    if(m[0].equals("hello")){
        m[1] = checkName(m[1]);
        users.put(m[1], null);
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("registered " + m[1]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(m[0].equals("join")){
        System.out.println("Client requested join");
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("gpp " + p.getGpp().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(m[0].equals("gppConf")){
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("gpk " + p.getGpk().toString());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(m[0].equals("gpkConf")){
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("startJoining");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(m[0].equals("verifyProof")){
        Random r = new Random();
        if(verifyProof(new BigInteger(m[1]), new BigInteger(m[2]), new BigInteger(m[2]), new BigInteger(m[4]))){
            System.out.println("Proof verified");
            BigInteger alfafala = new BigInteger(p.getGpp().getLx(), r);
            alfafala.setBit(0);
            BigInteger betafala = new BigInteger(p.getGpp().getLx(), r);
            try {
                dos.writeUTF("sendAB " + alfafala.toString() + " " + betafala.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Wrong proof");
        }
    }
}
```

Member:

```
public class Member {

private static String host = "localhost";
private static int port = 1234;
private static Primer pr;
private static String ident;
private static GroupPublicKey gpk;
private static GroupPublicParameter gpp;
private MemberSignatureKey msk;
private static ProofOfKnowledge U;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String[] args){
    InputStream inStream;
    pr = new Primer();
    DataInputStream inDataStream;
    OutputStream outStream;
    DataOutputStream outDataStream;
    String message = "";
    String received = "";
    try {
        InetAddress addr = InetAddress.getByName(host);
        Socket sock;
        sock = new Socket(addr, port);
        System.out.println("Chat Client Started");
        do{
            DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(System.in);
            message = dis.readLine();
            outStream = sock.getOutputStream();
            outDataStream = new DataOutputStream (outStream);       
            outDataStream.writeUTF(message);    
            inStream = sock.getInputStream();
            inDataStream = new DataInputStream ( inStream );
            received = inDataStream.readUTF();
            System.out.println("Server Sent: " + received);
            analyzeMSG(received, outDataStream);
            outDataStream.flush();
        }while(!message.equals("bye"));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

//private static boolean isPortAvailable(int port) { 

//}  

public static void analyzeMSG(String msg, DataOutputStream dos){
    String[] m = msg.split(" ");
    if(m[0].equals("registered")){
        ident = m[1];
    }
    if(m[0].equals("gpp")){
        gpp = new GroupPublicParameter(Integer.parseInt(m[1]), Integer.parseInt(m[2]), Integer.parseInt(m[3]), Integer.parseInt(m[4]), Integer.parseInt(m[5]), Integer.parseInt(m[6]), Double.parseDouble(m[7]));
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("gppConf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(m[0].equals("gpk")){
        gpk = new GroupPublicKey(new BigInteger(m[1]), new BigInteger(m[2]), new BigInteger(m[3]), new BigInteger(m[4]), new BigInteger(m[5]), new BigInteger(m[6]));
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("gpkConf");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(m[0].equals("startJoining")){
        try {
            dos.writeUTF("verifyProof " + startJoining());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    if(m[0].equals("sendAB")){
        System.out.println("Proof confirmed");
    }
}

public static String startJoining(){
    System.out.println("Started join");
    Random r = new Random();
    int scale = r.nextInt(gpp.getLx());
    BigInteger xfala = new BigInteger(scale, r);
    scale = ((gpk.getN().multiply(new BigInteger("2"))).subtract(new BigInteger("1"))).bitLength();
    BigInteger rfala = Primer.primeLessThan((gpk.getN().multiply(new BigInteger("2"))).subtract(new BigInteger("1")), scale);
    BigInteger C1 = (pr.pow(gpk.getG(), xfala).multiply(pr.pow(gpk.getH(), rfala))).mod(gpk.getN());
    genProof(C1, xfala, rfala);
    return C1.toString() + " " + U.toString();
}

private static void genProof(BigInteger C1, BigInteger xfala, BigInteger rfala){
    System.out.println("Generating Proof");
    Random r = new Random();
    BigInteger t1 = new BigInteger((int) (gpp.getTeta()*(gpp.getLx() + gpp.getK())), r);
    BigInteger t2 = new BigInteger((int) (gpp.getTeta()*((2*gpp.getLp()) + gpp.getK())) - 1, r);
    BigInteger D = (pr.pow(gpk.getG(), t1).multiply(pr.pow(gpk.getH(), t2))).mod(gpk.getN());
    BigInteger cfala = pr.H(gpk.getG().toString() + gpk.getH().toString() + C1.toString() + D.toString());
    BigInteger s1fala = t1.subtract(cfala.multiply(xfala));
    BigInteger s2fala = t2.subtract(cfala.multiply(rfala));
    U = new ProofOfKnowledge(cfala, s1fala, s2fala);
}
```

The problem is, after exchange of few messages, writeUTF method is called in Server,  but the message starting with "gpk" does not get sent until I retype the confirmation message (gppConf) that was sent before. From then I have to double every message in order for it to be received. What is the reason for that?

Comment: Suggestion: try setting [Socket.setTcpNoDelay](http://www.davidreilly.com/java/java_network_programming/#3.3), and see if that helps

Comment: Don't keep constructing new streams every time around the loop. Use the same streams for the life of the socket, at both ends.